# Xamarin Forms - add color in global resources from code

Tags: c#, android, resources, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

I use this color in global resources(in app.xaml)

```
       <Color x:Key="MyColor" x:FactoryMethod="FromHex">
            <x:Arguments>
                <x:String>#ffffff</x:String>
            </x:Arguments>
        </Color>
```

I need different colors for Android and Windows Phone. I tried this code:

```
       <Color x:Key="MyColor" x:FactoryMethod="FromHex">
            <x:Arguments>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                              Android="#006ABB"
                              WindowsPhone="#ffffff"  />
                <x:String></x:String>
            </x:Arguments>
        </Color>
```

but it not work. Tell me - how to add it in code behind. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in `App.xaml`, no need to go to code. Simply you need a little bit different approach. Here is the code

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <OnPlatform
        x:Key="MyColor"
        x:TypeArguments="Color"
        Android="#006ABB"
        iOS="#006A00"
        WinPhone="#ffffff"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

The reason why this works, is because `OnPlatform` generic class has implicit conversation operator defined which can convert each `OnPlatform` object to its inbound generic `T` class. Something like this

```
public static implicit operator T(OnPlatform<T> onPlatform)
```

Comment: It is not work. I get System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Comment: The issue is not because of this, you have other issue in your app. Can you post exception details from the Output?